# How do I write a function that counts the number of times a date occurs in my vector?

Tags: r, function, date

I am struggling to write a function that has two arguments and eventually prints out "There were X occurrences on DATE". I have am working with a large vector of dates in the format of yyyy-mm-dd, and have no idea where to go from here. I'll attach my work so far.

```
occurrences_function<- function(Date, vector_of_dates) {
   Date<- ?
   X <- length(Date)
   output<- paste("Records show there were", X, "occurrences on", Date"
   return(output)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer summing a boolean vector:

```r
occurrences_function <- function(Date, vector_of_dates) {
    count <- sum(vector_of_dates == Date)
    output <- paste("Records show there were", count, "occurrences on", Date)
    return(output)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! What would it look like it I was trying to connect the boolean vector? I attempted to do this but it is not outputting what I want it to say

Comment: Sorry...didn't see that you want to return a message, check the updated answer.